# Using encapsulation/functions to modify a variable and pass it to the current namespace

Tags: python, encapsulation

I'm trying to write a function which gets the header of a CSV file and stores it as a list, which will be useful later:

```
def getHeader(filename, headername):
     import csv
     charList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'] <<<---a lot longer
     headercsv = open(filename, 'r', newline = '')
     headerreader = csv.reader(headercsv, delimiter = ',')
     for row in headerreader:
         if row[0][0] in charList:
              headername = row

     headercsv.close()
     return headername
```

Then I do the following:

```
thisHeader = []
getHeader('csvfile.csv', thisHeader)
```

If I'm trying this in the shell, it returns the correct info, but when I try to look at the information contained within the variable `thisHeader`, it only returns `[]`, a blank list.

I also define another function to aggregate population info, across every entry, for each cohort.  It needs to use the header obtained in the above function and is defined as such:

```
def newPopCount(filename, fileheader, popholder):
     import csv
     cohorts = []
     for i in range (3, len(fileheader)):
          cohorts.append(fileheader[i])
     for i in range (len(cohorts)):
          popholder.append(0)

     popcsv = open(filename, 'r', newline = '')
     popreader = csv.reader(popcsv, delimiter = ',')

     for row in popreader:
         counter = 0
         if row[0] == fileheader[0]:
             continue
         else:
             for i in range(3, len(fileheader)):
                 popholder[counter] += int(row[i])
                 counter += 1

     popcsv.close()
     return popholder
```

I have these functions defined within another function, so as to only call the outer most function with a file name `test('csvfile.csv')` and then some print statements to assess whether the code is doing what it supposed to, by passing on the information obtained from one function to the other function - they are not.

Comment: Why don't you just do `thisHeader = getHeader('csvfile.csv')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you overcomplicating things?

```
def getHeader(filename):
     import csv
     headername = None
     charList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
     headercsv = open(filename, 'r', newline = '')
     headerreader = csv.reader(headercsv, delimiter = ',')
     for row in headerreader:
         if row[0][0] in charList:
              headername = row

     headercsv.close()
     return headername
```

Now you can:

```
thisHeader = getHeader('csvfile.csv')
```

Make sure you understand how functions work, and the difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference.

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, I definitively may be overcomplicating things!  I like your idea!  I'm going to try that out.  For the second function, would I do a similar thing by `totalPop = newPopCount('csvfile.csv', thisHeader)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You're wrestling with how python deals with references -- the assignment operator takes the object evaluated from the expression on the right and binds it to the local name on the left ("overwriting" anything that name referenced ahead of time).  So, a function like:

```
a = []
def foo(lst):
    lst = [1]

foo(a)
print a #[]
```

will never update `a`.  Instead, inside the function, you create a new list on the right side of the assignment and bind it to the *local* name on the left side of the argument.

This is basically the same thing as expecting:

```
a = []
b = a
b = [1]
print a #[]
```

to modify `a` (it won't).

You can however do operations which will mutate the list in the function:

```
def foo(lst):
    lst.append(1)

a = []
foo(a)
print a #[1]
```

In this last case, if you always expect to be inputting an empty list, it is more idiomatic to write something like:

```
def foo():
    return [1]

a = foo()
```

There's no need for the caller to create an empty list just to pass it into the function when you can *return* the populated list directly and let the caller do whatever they want with it.  (**This is the approach others are recommending in their answers, and I completely agree with them**).

---

Note that in python, it's typical for a function which modifies its arguments to return `None` to make it clear that the arguments are being mutated.  You'll sometimes see things like:

```
def foo(lst):
    a = [x*x for x in lst]
    return a

a = [1, 2, 3]
a = foo(a)  #Nothing wrong with this.
```

Comment: Thanks for the post.  I was defining an empty list `thisHeader = []` and then calling the function on the file and the empty list `getHeader('csvfile.csv', thisHeader)` and wanted the list to populate.  Does that make sense?  I think that's what you are talking about with mutating the list, but I may be misunderstanding...

Comment: @FortyLashes -- Yes, that's what I'm talking about.  Generally, it's more "pythonic" to *return* the stuff you want and leave it to the caller to handle.